# Excel Unique values

Tags: arrays, excel, formulas

Let's say you have 2 columns of data in excel:

```
name     Date
Bob      1/1/2013
Bob      1/5/2013
Joe      1/31/2013
Joe      1/15/2013
Charles  1/8/2013
Ted      1/6/2013
Fred     1/4/2013
George   2/2/2013
Hank     2/5/2013
Mary     6/2/2013
Mary     6/4/2013
Rob      6/4/2013
```

And then you are given a list of months:

```
Month
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
```

What would be the formula that counts the number of people born by month IF THEY Have the SAME NAME.

ONE huge cavet is that I ***CANNOT USE THE COUNTIF(s)*** formula. I think this would be an array formula of some sort.  Any ideas.

So results should look like:

```
Month  Count
1        2  --> births in Jan. for Bob and Joe but Charles and ted were not counted
2        0
3        1  --> There were 2 Marys  born in June
4        0
5        0
6        0
7        0
8        0
9        0
10       0
11       0
12       0
```

Comment: Why can't you use the Countifs formula? That's a rather odd limitation. Is this a homework problem?

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming the 1 should be against month 6 - the 2 Marys were born in June?

Assuming names in `A2:A13`, DOBs in `B2:B13` and months (numbers 1 to 12) in `D2:D13` then you can use this formula in E2 [revised to make less complex]

`=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(MONTH(B$2:B$13)=D2,MATCH(A$2:A$13,A$2:A$13,0)),ROW(A$2:A$13)-ROW(A$2)+1)>1,1))`

confirm with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> and copy down column

To get the total number of people in each month who share a birthday with another identically named person, also with a birthday in that month, you can use TEXT function like this to avoid repeating the FREQUENCY part, i.e.

`=SUM(TEXT(FREQUENCY(IF(MONTH(B$2:B$13)=D2,MATCH(A$2:A$13,A$2:A$13,0)),ROW(A$2:A$13)-ROW(A$2)+1),"[<2]""0"";0")+0)`

Comment: Awesome Barry!   However, I misinterpreted my problem. I actually need the total number of people. How hard would it be to return the total number of people instead of just the number of names.   So the Results would be 4 for January and 2 for June.  Is that possible too?

Comment: I added another version to my answer which should do that